# Wp private content show me files attachments into post

Tags: plugins, the-content, private

I'm using that plugin wp private content and it works fine, but (probably for a update) that show me at the final part of the post a box with link to download someting...in each post!
Even if the post have only a title and few words content, that show me the following:

[image: file-download]

Is possible to fix it or remove it?
The code of my single.php is just 3 div's:

```
<div>
<div><?php the_title();?>
<div><?php the_content();?>
</div>
```

Comment: The plugin author would be the best one to answer that... You can try to locate inside the plugin code the part that generates this and see if there is a filter you can use to remove it. Otherwise, you can use CSS to hide it.

Answer (score 0):

Like said @brasofilo, I check the plugin author page and is a usual problem (more people post the same error).

So I decided to hide with CSS. Thanks!